# horizontal lift along fibres

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $f:X\setminus D\to Y$ be a smooth family of Kahler manifolds, where $D=\{\sigma=0\}$ is a divisor on $X$. Taking a local
coordinate $(s_1,...,s_d)$ of
$Y$
and a local coordinate $(z_1,...,z_n)$ of a fiber of
$f$, $(z_1,...,z_n,\sigma, s_2,...,s_d)$ forms a local coordinate of
$X\setminus D$
such that under this coordinate,
the holomorphic mapping
$f$
is locally given by
$f(z_1,...,z_n,\sigma, s_2,...,s_d) = (\sigma, s_2,...,s_d)$

Now take $\omega$ be a $(1,1)$-form on $X'=X\setminus D$. We can write:

$$\omega=\sqrt{-1}\left(\omega_{z_i\bar z_j}dz_i\wedge d\bar z_j+\omega_{z_i\bar s_j}dz_i\wedge d\bar s_j+\omega_{s_i\bar z_j}ds_i\wedge d\bar z_j+\omega_{s_i\bar s_j}ds_i\wedge d\bar s_j+\omega_{\sigma\bar \sigma}d\sigma\wedge d\bar \sigma+\omega_{\sigma\bar z_j}d\sigma\wedge d\bar z_j+\omega_{z_i\bar \sigma}dz_i\wedge d\bar \sigma+\omega_{s_i\bar \sigma}ds_i\wedge d\bar \sigma+\omega_{\sigma\bar s_j}d\sigma\wedge d\bar s_j\right)$$

Is the $\omega$-horizontal lift of type $(1, 0)$ of the tangent vector $\partial/\partial s_j$ equal to:

$$\partial/\partial s_j-\omega_{i\bar \beta}\omega^{\bar \beta\alpha}\partial/\partial z_i?$$ 
Can someone give a proof? See page 4 http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2966.pdf

What is the horizontal lift of $\partial/\partial \sigma$?

Comment: I don't see a reason why $\sigma$ should be a horizontal coordinate. Do you assume that $D$ is a union of fibers of $f$, so that in fact $D=(\sigma\circ f)^{-1}(0)$? And do you want $\omega$ to be Kähler, or at least nondegenerate?

Comment: $D$ is a simple normal crossing divisor with conical or cusp singularities. The restriction of $\omega $ on each fibre $X_s\setminus D_s$ is Kahler

Comment: It seems there is a typo in your formula for the $\omega$-horizontal lift of $\partial s_j$. Namely, the super-index $\alpha$ is neither contracted nor related to $s_j$, isnt' it ?

Comment: $\omega^{\bar \beta\alpha} $ is just $\omega^{\bar z_i z_j}$, sorry for typo

Comment: At page 5 of the paper you refered is defined "the horizontal lift" of $\partial s_j$.  Can you indicated where is the definition of $\omega$-horizontal lift ?  Or they are the same thing?

Comment: See page 3 http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00323v2

Comment: Did you see page 4 Remark 2.1. of this paper?. There you can see the formula for the horizontal lift. So I do not understand what are you asking for. Are you looking for a detailed proof of the formula for the horizontal lift in Remark 2.1. at page 4 ?

Comment: That formula is for non divisorial version. I am looking for proof